# How do I remove the white edges around div tags?

Tags: html, css

I've noticed how on some websites, the headers have no edges or excessive whitespace, I am trying to recreate something similar, but not really sure how to. A good example would be the top notification/search bar on stackoverflow itself.

```
.header
{
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#ffa200), color-stop(100%,#d25400));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffa200',endColorstr='#d25400',GradientType=0);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#ffa200,#d25400);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#ffa200,#d25400);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.header .topbar
{
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url(../imgz/head/hBarSBg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.header .topbar .mCquake
{
    height: 37px;
    width: 278px;
    background-image: url(../imgz/head/mCqRight.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 11.5px;
    margin-bottom: 11.5px;
}
```

How exactly would I go about doing this?

Thanks. :)

Comment: where's the rest of your code? how are we supposed to see what's wrong? and what is this "whitespace" and "edges" you are talking about?

Comment: It's fixed, the probably was that the browser's were using the default values for html and body tags (margin and padding) which caused extra whitespace around my header tag. It was pointed out in earlier comments and is now fixed, thanks though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the people use some default css declarations to bring all browsers to the same level. One that is gaining attention recently is http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/ -- You can also type CSS Resets on google and it will give you bunch of results :D

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to set the body margin to 0.

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to reset the default `paddings` and `margins` set by the browsers

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px; 
  outline: none;
  border: 0px;
}
```

This will also help your CSS styles to work on different browsers similarly.

Comment: I would recommend using `html, body` rather than `*` since you might rely on default padding/margin of some elements.

Comment: @AramKocharyan for this particular example, resetting margin for `body` is enough. But a global CSS reset includes resetting all the defaults values to 0, thus enabling element styles to have the same values in all the browsers.